# Stan (pystan) creating a vector of ints to assign to a categorical distribution

Tags: python-3.x, stan, pystan

First time using Stan.  [I am starting with an example found on a Coursera class where they're using JAGS](https://www.coursera.org/learn/mcmc-bayesian-statistics/lecture/KDEVZ/mixture-model-in-jags) which I am trying to reimplement in Stan.  The class is free to audit and I have linked the relevant lecture.

**Background on the model:**

(I don't see how to use LaTeX so I'll try to format this as well as possible):
The model is a mixture model where the input is a vector `n` of real numbers with `2` potential classes.  They assume that these classes are `Z_1 ~ N(mu_1, stdev)` and `Z_2 ~ N(mu_2, stdev)` (it is a mixture of 2 Normals, with different `mu`'s but the same `stdev`).
They are assuming a uniform Dirichlect prior with  `alpha=1` on the probability of being in each class.

Each data point is drawn from a categorical distribution based on the probability vector and they increment the likelihood with the corresponding Normal likelihood.

**My code**

```
model_code_coursera = """
data {
    int<lower=1> N;         //Num Samples
    int<lower=1> K;         //Num classes
    real y[N];              //Input which we are trying to assign to each class
} parameters {
    simplex[K] probs;       //Prob of being in each class
    vector[K] mu;           //Center of each class
    real<lower=0> prec;
    vector<lower=0, upper=K>[N] z; //Array of classes ****(option 1)****
    int<lower=0, upper=K>[N] z;  // Array of classes ****(option 2)****
} model {
    probs ~ dirichlet(rep_vector(1,K));
    prec ~ gamma(1/2, 2/2);
    for (k in 1:K)
        mu[k] ~ normal(-1+2*(k-1), 1/100);
    for (n in 1:N) {
        z[n] ~ categorical(probs);
        y[n] ~ normal(mu[z[n]], prec);
    }
}
"""
```

When I use option 1 I get the error,

```
No matches for: 
  real ~ categorical(vector)
Available argument signatures for categorical:
  int ~ categorical(vector)
```

which makes sense as the output of a categorical is an int.

However, when I do what makes sense and define z to be a vector of ints as [I see in Stan cheat sheets](http://www.sumsar.net/files/posts/2017-bayesian-tutorial-exercises/stan_cheat_sheet2.12.pdf) I get a different error (option 2)

```
    10:     int<lower=0, upper=K>[N] z;  // Array of classes
                                ^
    11: } model {
  -------------------------------------------------

PARSER EXPECTED: <identifier>
```

Answer (score -1):

Stan does not directly support integer parameters.  To implement a normal mixture model of the variety described in the question, the discrete parameters must be marginalized out.  There's an explanation of how to do this in the [Stan user's guide chapter on mixture models](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_23/stan-users-guide/mixture-modeling-chapter.html).  The upside is that mixing is much better w/o discrete parameters and inferences in expectation are more precise.